# Syntax error in COPY FROM thrown by postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, import

I'm trying to import data from a pipe-delimited text file into my Postgres `data_master` table. My command looks like this:

```
COPY data_master FROM '/Users/me/Documents/DATA/39079.txt' 
    WITH FORMAT csv, 
    DELIMITER '|', 
    HEADER TRUE;
```

Here's the error:

```
temp=# COPY data_master FROM '/Users/me/Documents/DATA/39079.txt' WITH FORMAT csv, DELIMITER '|', HEADER TRUE;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FORMAT"
LINE 1: .../me/Documents/DATA/39079.txt' WITH FORMAT csv...
                                              ^
temp=# show server_version;
-[ RECORD 1 ]--+-----
server_version | 10.1
```

From the docs this seems like a valid syntax for the command. What did I do wrong?

EDIT: I tried this after removing the commas as well, with the same results:

```
temp=# COPY data_master FROM '/Users/me/Documents/DATA/39079.txt' WITH FORMAT CSV DELIMITER '|' HEADER TRUE;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FORMAT"
LINE 1: .../me/Documents/DATA/39079.txt' WITH FORMAT CSV...
                                              ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax following `WITH` should be in parentheses.

```
COPY data_master FROM '/Users/me/Documents/DATA/39079.txt' 
  WITH (
    FORMAT csv, 
    DELIMITER '|', 
    HEADER TRUE
  );
```